# Passing Data to Multiple instances of User Control in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am developing the desktop application using WPF with MVVM architecture, In which, I created one User Control (View) contains the Menu control and its Menu Items would be added dynamically from its View Model.

Above things are working perfectly. But the thing is, I want to re-use the above user control in order to create multiple Menu's in different locations in the view with different menu Items data.

My View Model need to know Menu name (or some param value) in order to fetch its corresponding Menu Items and add it to Menu dynamically.

Please help me out how to pass the data/menu name to the View Model?

Regards,
Srihari.

Comment: I can´t understand you completely. Can you post your code, where you use the menu name? Usually the ViewModel should´nt know anything about the view, to make it most reusable.

You should bind the ItemsSource-Property of your Menu to a Property in your ViewModel. For each location in your application you can use the same User-Control with a different ViewModel in Data-Context. Of course all the ViewModels need the same Property. Only the way you fill the Property is different.

Comment: Where do you create your ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

I take your question to mean that you have a ViewModel that when given a string will get the appropriate menu items?

If so I would think something like this would do the trick? If not please provide some code so we can follow your thought process.

**AllMenuItemsViewModel.cs**

```
public AllMenuItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> _allMenuItems;

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> AllMenuItems
    {
        get { return _allMenuItems; }
    }

    public AllMenuItemsViewModel(string menuName)
    {
        CreateAllMenuItems(menuName);
    }

    private void CreateAllMenuItems(string menuName)
    {
        var allItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();

        // Add items to allItems based on provided string.

        _allMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>(allMenuItems);
    }
}
```

**ParentViewModel.cs**

```
public ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly AllMenuItemsViewModel _mainMenuItems;
    private readonly AllMenuItemsViewModel _subMenuItems;

    public AllMenuItemsViewModel MainMenuItems
    {
        get { return _mainMenuItems; }
    }

    public AllMenuItemsViewModel SubMenuItems
    {
        get { return _subMenuItems; }
    }

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        _mainMenuItems = new AllMenuItemsViewModel("Main");
        _subMenuItems = new AllMenuItemsViewModel("Sub");
    }
}
```